# Does install4j have option that JRE doesn't extract

Tags: install4j

My product is made by install4j has already installed.

when the same product re-install, Does install4j have option that JRE doesn't extract ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Installer->Screens & Actions, search for the "Install files" action and deselect the "Update bundled JRE" property.